# AJAX is skipping success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My Ajax function is skipping my success function, but yet I can still get my php script to run.

Below is my JavaScript function containing my AJAX call. Here's an explanation of what I'm experiencing:

- If I put a `alert("msg");` in my success function, it NEVER gets hit.
  It goes to the error function every time.
- However, if I put an `alert("error");` in my error function, then my php file still runs and my data is entered into the database correctly.
- If I removed `alert("error");` from the error function, my php file does not run and nothing is added.

... It's almost as if I need that alert message in my error function to halt the code (or something), in order for my my php file to run.

Does this make sense to anyone?

```
<script>
  function AddItem(){
    var name   = document.forms["additemform"]["nc_name"].value;
    var tag    = document.forms["additemform"]["nc_tag"].value;
    var table  = "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserItemTable']; ?>";

    var isValid = false;
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/AddItem.php",  
      data: { 
        "Item_Name": name, 
        "Tag_Num": tag, 
        "Table_Name": table 
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        alert('msg");
        if(resp.reply == "Success")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
      },
      error: function(data, status){
        console.log(data, status);
        alert("error");
      }
    }); //end Ajax
```

The message that is dumped out in my console is this:

```
{
  readyState: 0, 
  getResponseHeader: function, 
  getAllResponseHeaders: function, 
  setRequestHeader: function, 
  overrideMimeType: function, 
…}
```

Not sure why my code is not executed...

Comment: Any other console errors or network errors (look in browser's network tab)? They might be more descriptive. Pretty sure a successful response requires a `readyState` of `4`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have this typo in your code as well as in this example, but you have written:

```
alert('msg");
```

... both a single and a double-quote. That screws up the execution.